# Test Users for qq / tencent

Tags: microblogging

Is there an API that tencent / QQ provides to create test users (just like facebook?)?  I have developer creds and api documentation seems to be pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

here is provided a wonderful sdk with sample code

http://wiki.opensns.qq.com/wiki/%E3%80%90QQ%E7%99%BB%E5%BD%95%E3%80%91IOS_SDK%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E